# How to create a form in Brython where entering a name hides the form and displays a welcome message in a div?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, brython

I want to implement a functionality using `Brython` where I have a form that allows me to enter my name. Once I enter my name and submit the form, I want the form to disappear and a div to appear with a welcome message displaying "Welcome, [name]" where [name] is the name I entered.

I have tried the following code, but it's not working as expected:

```
from browser import document, html, window

storage = window.localStorage 
form = document.getElementById("name-form")
div = document.getElementById("welcome")
if storage["name"]:
    form.style.display = "none"
    div.style.display = "block"
else:
    form.style.display = "block"
    div.style.display = "none"
```

However, when I run the code, I encounter the following error: `"brython.js:6594 Uncaught dir ... [full error message]"`

I have verified that I have included the necessary `Brython` script tags in my HTML file. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this functionality correctly using `Brython`?

error message:

brython.js:6594 Uncaught **dir**
at Object.eval [as $factory] (eval at $B.$make_exc (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:7807:20), :5:15)
at $B.attr_error (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:7834:27)
at $B.JSObj.**getattribute** (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:9336:10)
at $B.$getattr (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:6582:9)
at *b*.dir (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:6322:35)
at offer_suggestions_for_attribute_error (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:7898:13)
at $B.error_trace (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:8031:117)
at $B.show_error (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:8038:42)
at $B.handle_error (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.11.2/brython.js:8046:4)
at $B.loop (https://cdnjs.clou

Comment: The "full error message" would be interesting.

Comment: Ok, i've edited and put the message there

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to interpret the error message without the complete context, but here is a minimal example that does what you want:

```
<script type="text/python">
from browser import bind, document, html, window

@bind('#name-form', 'click')
def welcome(ev):
    form = document.select_one('form')
    name = document["name-input"].value
    form.remove()
    document["welcome"].text = f'Welcome, {name} !'
</script>

<form method="get" action="#">
<input id="name-input" name="name">
<input id="name-form" type="submit">
</form>

<div id="welcome"></div>
```